# Expo Push Notifications Not Pushing to Physical Device

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo

My application in React Native using Expo was sending notifications beautifully using the code below to all of the tokens stored in Firebase. Now, after I published my app on the Expo.io website, it won't work and won't push any notification to any physical device at all. I have tried to rebuild the project in my local machine and run expo on my phone from my computer, and I console logged the information and all of the expo token information is correct and being pulled correctly. Why are the notifications not pushing now to any physical device? Please help. The try block below executes without error, but why aren't notifications pushing then? My component did mount also calls loadInformation & generateToken, and my render and return just call the sendPushNotif function when the user presses the send notification button.

> My this.state.finalArray console logs the following:  "Array [
> Object {
> "body": "test",
> "title": "this is a test",
> "to": Array [
> "ExponentPushToken[.......]",
> "ExponentPushToken[........]",
> ],   }, ]"

```
constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            tokenArray: [],
            finalArray: [],
        }
    }

loadInformation = async () => {
    var tokens = []
    firebase.database().ref('tokens/`).once('value', snapshot => {
        const token = Object.values(snapshot.val());
        token.map((item) => {
            tokens.push(item.data)
            return this.setState({ tokenArray: tokens })
        })
    })
}

generateToken = async () => {
    this.state.finalArray = []
    this.state.finalArray.push({
        to: this.state.tokenArray,
        title: this.state.title,
        body: this.state.notification
    })
}

sendPushNotification = async () => {
  //these functions load all the token info from firebase and stores it into an array
  this.loadInformation();
  this.generateToken();
  try {
    let response = await fetch("https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(this.state.finalArray), //final array has all the tokens and title and body info for the notif. i console logged this and it outputs the correct info
    });
    alert("Your notification was sent!");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    alert("Error! Your notification was not sent.");
  }
};
```

Comment: Show your tokens....I mean show me `this.state.finalArray` Because I think you are sending Push Notification to `ExpoPushToken` instead of `DevicePushToken`

Comment: @KartikeyVaish i added the way i initialize this array and how i grab my info from firebase. i also put what this.state.finalArray displays (i took out the actual push token but it is correct). please let me know if you can help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Answer
As expo handle the notification registration for IOS but for android you have to register your app with firebase

So you have to register your app with firebase for this
Click here to get full information
https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/using-fcm/
all steps are mentioned
OR for Video information Click here
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oRNwNintDW0

Comment: This is what ended up being the issue for me -- my app was already registered with Firebase but I specifically had to create an Android App in the project, run eas build, and add the FCM Key in my Expo Server -- only then did notifications start displaying

Answer (score 0):

The tokens you have in `this.state.finalArray` are Expo Push token which every Expo Go app has. So it will not work in Production as every device has its own `devicePushToken`.

`ExponentPushToken[........]` tokens work only on `Expo Go` App and not in Production. See [this](https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/sending-notifications-custom/#how-do-i-write-my-own-apns)

Comment: My code is working now on Expo Go, but only send if the user is not in the Expo Go app itself. How come? And ah, this is horrible because I am also going to deploy on Apple as well so I wish i went through this documentation earlier :( Thanks for this, but not sure why my code won't send if expo go is running.

Comment: actually oddly enough, notifications are working for me for the beta testing phase after deploying for Apple? but again they only work if the user is not currently using the app (theyre on the homescreen or in another app). so odd